# Having an method argument as 'Object' type

Tags: java

Suppose I have the following method:-

```
public static void abhay(Object a){
....
}
```

and I use it somewhere like this:-

```
public static void main(String[] args){
...
Kaal b = new Kaal();
abhay(b);
...
}
```

where `Kaal` is a class, obviously.

Now, what will be the class type(object type at compile time) of `a` inside the method `abhay`? In other words, what will be the class of `a`, in the eyes of compiler, when inside method `abhay`?

Also, how above is different than below?

(given that we only change the definition of `abhay`):-

```
public static void abhay(Kaal a){
....
}
```

"Java is always '**call by value**'. Instead of the object, only the reference to the object, is passed as an argument, where this reference, is, the value."

If the above fact has any relevance to the answer to this question, please try to explain in context of above fact.

Comment: `"...and I use it somewhere like this:-..."` -- and that won't compile

Comment: The code you've posted wouldn't compile, making it particularly hard to answer you - and it's already hard enough as your question isn't terribly clear. But the compile-time type of `a` in the first case is `Object`, as you'd find out if you tried to use any of the methods declared in `Kaal`...

Comment: It'll be an Object. You're welcome to cast it and check it's type, though

Comment: This may be a decent place to use generics, ... but I'm not sure based on your question.

Comment: @amsquareb Avoid naming methods after actual names of people.

Comment: "Call by value" semantics has nothing to do with the type of the object. It will be the type declared in the method's formal parameters. The actual run-time type is irrelevant, as is "call by value."

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am terribly sorry. That was really a silly mistake I made. Actually I am new to Java and do not have much coding experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is straight forward. Given the following method signature:

```
public static void abhay(Object a)
```

and you invoke it by `abhay(new Kaal());`

It is like saying:

```
Object a = new Kaal();  //only able to access members of Object
```

Because you told Java to handle it as an Object, it will be treated as an Object. To access members of `Kaal`:

```
((Kaal)a).kaalMethod();
```

---

This is just a matter of Java complying to the data type given in the parameter list. It has nothing to do with "pass by value". Further more, both instances Kaal and Object are objects. You are not even dealing with primitives here where the value are referring to the actual content of the primitives.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler **only** cares about the signature of the method it is currently in.

It can't know and doesn't care about how that method is invoked.

So, to the compiler sees that `abhay()` has declared `a` to be an Object; and that is what the compiler knows about `a`.

Of course, at runtime, a call like `b instanceof Kaal` will result to `true`.

And just for the record: this has **nothing** to do with call-by-value or call-by-reference.

Answer (score 0):

Take `Kaal` as a parameter and you can access `Kaal` methods

```
public static void abhay(Kaal a){
    a.getSomeKaalMethod(); // works
    ....
}
```

Take `Object` as a parameter, and pass a `Kaal` class, and you can't access `Kaal` methods or fields

```
 public static void abhay(Object a){
     a.getSomeKaalMethod(); // doesnt work
     ....
 }
```

Unless you cast the object to `Kaal`

```
public static void abhay(Object a){
     Kaal k = (Kaal)a;
     k.getSomeKaalMethod(); // works
     ....
}
```

You might want to check if is `instanceof` `Kaal` other wise I dont see why  you will take a `Object` instead of the class

```
public static void abhay(Object a){
    if(a instanceof Kaal){
        Kaal k = (Kaal)a;
        k.getSomeKaalMethod(); // works
    }
}
```